# Does city municipal code apply to the towns that are part of it in New York?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, jurisdiction

I was reading the [Towing Municipal Code](https://ecode360.com/8679025) for the City of Rochester (New York, USA) and was curious if the municipal code applied to my jurisdiction. Specifically I reside in the [Town of Henrietta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta,_New_York) and I'm curious if the above towing code applies here, but maybe you can answer in a more general sense? What I'm looking for is a Yes or No and a reference for that answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In New York State, towns are not "part of" cities; they are distinct political entities with their own separate borders, and they do not overlap or contain each other.  You can see on [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_County,_New_York#/media/File:Monroe_County_(New_York)_-_Towns,_Villages,_and_City.svg) (Wikipedia but I couldn't find an official one that was as easy to read) that the Town of Henrietta and the City of Rochester are separate.  In fact, they do not even share a common border (the Town of Brighton is in between).

The laws and municipal code of the City of Rochester do not apply in the Town of Henrietta, nor vice versa.  Henrietta has its own [Town Code](https://ecode360.com/HE0056?needHash=true), linked from its [official website](https://www.henrietta.org/), but I could not find any regulations on towing vehicles from private property, nor in the [Code of Monroe County](https://www.ecode360.com/MO0860) in which the Town is located.  So I would assume that [New York State law](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/GBS/399-V) applies.